# css floats or jquery masonry tumblr?

Tags: css, jquery-masonry

Trying to design a custom tumblr theme. I want text posts to float text left of images, and I want the remaining images to display like they do in masonry ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyIKj.png)). Is this possible with a single column masonry layout?

Also would like to integrate endless scrolling. Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: What have tried already? Can you put up a test case?

Comment: Just to clarify: You only want text posts to be placed in the leftmost column, but image posts could be placed anywhere?